# JSF - CDI instancing again a session bean

Tags: multithreading, jsf, ejb, cdi

The source code:

```
public class ReportGenerator implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3995091296520157208L;
    @Inject
    private ReportCacheSession reportCacheSession;
    @Inject
    private UserSessionBean userSessionBean;
    @Inject
    private Instance<ReportBuilder> reportBuilderInstance;

    public static final int BUILD_ERROR = 0;
    public static final int BUILD_OK = 1;
    public static final int BUILD_NOPAGES = 2;

    private ReportBuilder reportBuilder = null;

    private FileData build(String jasperName, Map<String, Object> params, String extension, boolean guardarCache, boolean inline) {
        FileData fd = null;

        reportBuilder = reportBuilderInstance.get();
        if (reportBuilder != null) {
            reportBuilder.jasperName = jasperName;
            reportBuilder.emailName = SevUtils.getEmailName(userSessionBean.getUserInfo().getEmail());
            reportBuilder.sessionId = JSFUtils.getSessionId();
            reportBuilder.params = params;
            reportBuilder.extension = extension;
            //reportBuilder.config(jasperName, SevUtils.getEmailName(userSessionBean.getUserInfo().getEmail()), JSFUtils.getSessionId(), params, extension);
            reportBuilder.start();

            try {
                reportBuilder.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ReportGenerator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            fd = reportBuilder.getFileData();
        }

        if (fd != null && fd.getState() == BUILD_OK) {
            fd.setInline(inline);

            if (guardarCache) {
                reportCacheSession.addReport(fd);
            }
        }

        return fd;
    }
}
```

reportBuilder.start(); is a new Thread to generate the report(s), the problem is when the line reportCacheSession.addReport(fd); is called CDI create a new instance each time, but ReportCacheSession is a session bean annotated with javax.inject.Named and javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped.

I don't know why this happens, but my solution is add a new line, like this:

```
FileData fd = null;
reportCacheSession.toString(); //NEW LINE
reportBuilder = reportBuilderInstance.get();
```

reportCacheSession.toString(); create the instance of ReportCacheSession before my thread is called and all works OK...

How the new thread affects to CDI? Why CDI created a new instance of my session bean when I called the thread before?

**UPDATE 08/15/12:**

Ok, I have changed  my code to use the EJB annotation @Asynchronous, in this case I have problem when I'm generating a large PDF report (the XLS report works without problem), the file's size is incomplete(less bytes) and when I try to open it this appear in blank... Maybe a problem/bug with JRExporter#exportReport method...

**LAST UPDATE:**

Ok, the report generation was my mistake... the question is **which alternative is best to use EJB Asynchronous or JMS?** Thanks to all, each comment have led me to find a good solution...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this code is kind of a wtf. You're starting a new and unmanaged thread (which is at its own already a big design mistake in a Java EE application, but that aside) and immediately after starting it, you're joining it! (i.e. you're letting the current thread wait for it to finish) What's in this case the benefit of doing the job in a separate thread instead of just in the current thread which is actually doing nothing all that time?

Comment: I need to finish that thread, is to avoid continue processing reports that take a long of time... Or when the user close the browser's tab/window , cancel that thread... Create a new thread in EE App is a bad practice, but I don't know about another solution...

Comment: ReportGenerator is injected from a bean annotated with ViewScoped (custom scope created to work with CDI), I need a good solution to control the report processing, I need to cancel it (i.e. when the user close the browser)

Comment: If report generation is such a heavy duty task that you need to be able to cancel it (BTW: not if a browser is closed, but if its session expires), you are probably much better off if you decouple the systems and use a more enterprisy asynchronous approach like JMS queues and corresponding notification messages. Or maybe allow offline generation and notify the users if the report are generated.

Comment: i would say look into whichever EE container you are using, there is probably an implementation of the "work api" that you can hook into for asynchronous work tasks.  that way you're using threads managed by the container and avoiding many headaches that the container is supposed to solve for you.

Comment: I changed my code to use the EJB Asynchronous annotation, apparently all is working, but I have a problem when the thread is generating the PDF report (the file's length is incomplete, blank report, maybe a problem with the exportReport method, no problem when I export to XLS), I use a different thread for each report (can be PDF or XLS), what option is better EJB Asynchronous or JMS? With my wrong code "all was working ok", apparently... :/

Comment: better to update the question than loosing ourselves here in the comment section...